# error while compiling a C++ code in MacBook

Tags: macos

I was trying to compile the open-source code MOOSE in my local machine which is MacBookPro. The code was compiling fine but then somehow something got changed by myself while exploring the code. And now I get lots of these annoying warning messages when I try to compile it.

```
/Users/subhenduchakraborty/Desktop/MyRepository/moose_ForDiscoFluxM//framework/build/unity_src/functormaterials_Unity.C:6:9: warning: non-portable path to file '"Userss/subhenduchakraborty/Desktop/MyRepository/moose_ForDiscofluxM//framework/src/functormaterials/GenericFunctorMaterial.C"'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
#include"/Users/subhenduchakraborty/Desktop/MyRepository/moose_ForDiscoFluxM//framework/src/functormaterials/GenericFunctorMaterial.C"
```

Despite this, code compiles and runs without any problem.

I have this repo also hosted in private GitLab. I cloned it again in my local machine but the warning message is still there.

Irony is, when I clone the same repo in my institution's HPC, it compiles without any problem or warning.

I was searching for that path inside the code, in the $PATH, and in ~/.bash* but no where to found.

Does anyone has any idea what is causing this warning.
Form where is it getting that path `/Userss/subhenduchakraborty/`? I do not have such folder in root. I have `/Users/subhenduchakraborty`.

Best
Subhendu

Comment: The warning says that you have capitalisation wrong on the `#include`. *nix based systems will happily accept it, because they ignore case on files, but Windows would fail - hence this this non-portable.

Comment: It's a bit odd that the path mentioned in the error message is not the same path as you use in the `#include` though

Comment: `moose_ForDiscofluxM` vs `moose_ForDiscoFluxM`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is given in the error description:

> specified path differs in case from file name on disk

The file you're trying to include uses lowercase `f` "moose_ForDisco**f**luxM", but the file on disk uses uppercase `F` "moose_ForDisco**F**luxM"